# How can I persist UserState while testing a bot?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, state-management

I'm trying to test a dialog which has `userState`. The `userState` creates a `userProfile` and this has to go step to step. I tried to pass `userState` into my `Dialog`'s constructor and this works when I use cosmos db for my storage. However when I'm testing I have trouble to set up my cosmos db into `userState`. In `Startup.cs` this is normally done for me, but I'm not totally sure I understand it. I've tried to use a `MemoryStorage` but this doesn't carry my info step to step.

I pass it into my dialog constructor like this:

```
public class MyDialog: ComponentDialog
{
    private UserState _userState;
    public MyDialog(UserState userState)
           : base(nameof(MyDialog))`
     {
         _userState = userState;
          ...
```

I have two steps that I need state to be saved through

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile= await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile());
            UserProfile.Name = (string)stepContext.Result;
            ...
```

And then this also needs to be used in another step:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile= await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile());
            ...
```

In my test dialog I have:

```
UserState userState;
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test_MyDialog()
        {
            userState = new UserState(new MemoryStorage());
            var myDialog = new MyDialog (userState);
            ...
```

But as I said before this doesn't carry through from my `SecondStep` to `ThirdStep`. This carries through ifI'm just running my bot normally, but doesn't with a test and I think it's due to `MemoryStorage`. Is this problem possible to solve using `MemoryStorage`? If not, what should I use or how can I use cosmos storage within the testing environment? Thank you.

Comment: So you want to use CosmosDbStorage instead of MemoryStorage in your test dialog ?